# Camera movement 2.0

Tags: animation, camera

As the camera is moving down the line, it doesn't stop at the end [image]

I'm very new to animation so it's probable an easy fix :)

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to go to *Output Properties* and change my ending frame